# Extension created via contentful-cli does not load on localhost

Tags: reactjs, contentful

I was trying to create my own UI field extension using the steps given on Contentful documents below:
https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/ui-extensions/managing-a-ui-extension/

For some reason my localhost:1234 server runs but nothing is loaded... The sdk's init function does not seem to fire due to which there is nothing getting added in the root div.

I also tried cloning the sample extension
https://github.com/contentful/extensions/tree/master/samples/external-api
This too does not load anything on localhost

Please help if anyone has successfully tried this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contentful DevRel here.

The idea behind [Contentful UI extensions](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/ui-extensions/) and [Apps](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/app-framework/) is that they are websites that run in an `iframe` in the the Contentful UI.

```
// the below callback will only be called 
// when the code runs in a iframe in the Contentful UI
window.contentfulExtension.init(function (sdk) {
  var value = sdk.field.getValue();
  sdk.field.setValue("Hello world!");
});
```

You're right, that the `init` block above is not firing when you're opening your locally running extension server in your browser. The reason here is that the Extensions SDK provides functionality and communication with the surrounding Contentful Interface. Without Contentful UI around it, it won't work.

The SDK will only call your `init` callback when `localhost` or any other URL is loaded inside the Contentful UI. For a development flow of UI Extensions or Apps `localhost` will be loaded right in the UI until you deploy your extension. :)

I don't know how you set up your extension so far, but I recommend to have a look at [the video in the docs that you linked](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/ui-extensions/managing-a-ui-extension/). It goes into detail of how to set up a UI extension in the Contentful UI.